# add multiple shortcuts fot the same macro

Tags: mutt

I am using these macros for quickly changing account in mutt.

```
macro index,pager <f1> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/comptes/University<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
macro index,pager <f2> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/comptes/Gmail<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
macro index,pager <f3> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/comptes/Petur<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```

But I am also using keyboard without F. keys. So I would like to bind these macros to two keys f1 and cu (for pressing c then u), f2 and cg and f3 and cp.

I tried something like `macro index,pager <f1>,cu ...` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need two macro definitions when you want to have 2 bindings. But you can specify an existing key binding as macro sequence.

With this you bind your first macro definition to (1) the F1 key and (2) key combination c, u:

```
macro index,pager <f1> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/comptes/University<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
macro index,pager cu <f1>
```